# After changing ram size of my VM Oracle Database not starting

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-xe

I have been using oracle xe on centos vm, previously vm has 4gb ram and it all was working fine, whenever i change ram size to 2gb oracle database stops connecting to sqldeveloper and start giving me error

**ORA-12505 Listener does not currently
know of SID given in connect descriptor**

Any idea how this can be fixed

Comment: Please check if oracle instance is registered with listener using LSNRCTL SERVICES.

Comment: Thank you for such a prompt response, i tried to you above and below is the result i got i think it is registered

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER

Comment: What it has to do with the ram size though how is that making it to not start

Comment: Database processes were not started because too large parameters are set .memory_target for the amount of memory in 2GB. The process of the listener started, but database is not started, incoming connections can not be established with the database. You should find the error code in the diagnostic file.`cd /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace   tail -100 alert_XE.log`

Comment: Thank you  Dmitry Demin yes you are right , I found this error 
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
WARNING: You are trying to use the MEMORY_TARGET feature. This feature requires the /dev/shm file system to be mounted for at least 1073741824 bytes. /dev/shm is either not mounted or is mounted with available space less than this size. Please fix this so that MEMORY_TARGET can work as expected. Current available is 927498240 and used is 0 bytes. Ensure that the mount point is /dev/shm for this directory.
memory_target needs larger /dev/shm

Comment: Since i cannot access database how can i change memory_target or check if /dev/shm is mounted?

Comment: One solution i did is changed /dev/shm size to 2gb and it started working again, but is there any other way to get around this like changing memory target size of oracledatabase etc.